# Is there an experiment where participant tries to move object with brain-machine interface and object is moved by someone else?

Tags: perception

Psychological experiment where subjects are first taught to move a object just by thinking about moving it (subject's brains are being read with a machine that moves the object). Then the object is being moved by someone else and subject only sees the object moving. As a result would subject think that he or she moved the object?

At the moment I am thinking that the answer would be yes, which is somewhat counterintuitive. Please prove me wrong. Thank you.